# ngx-bootstrap@0.0.1 being installed on angular version 14.2 project

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

To reproduce create a new angular project using Angular version 14.2, ng new ngxbootstrap. Then in project folder, ngxbootstrap, run ng add ngx-bootstrap.

When I perform the steps above, this is what I get.

> Using package manager: npm
> Found compatible package version: ngx-bootstrap@0.0.1.
> Package information loaded.
>
> The package ngx-bootstrap@0.0.1 will be installed and executed.
> Would you like to proceed? (Y/n)

On the ngx-bootstrap compatibility page, it states that ngx-bootstrap 10.2 is compatible with Angular 14.x

Anyone know the best way to resolve?

I tried the steps mentioned above on a new Angular project. I expected ngx-bootstrap version 10 would be installed.

Below is my package.json.

```
{
  "name": "ngxbootstrap",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.10",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your rxjs version?

Comment: "rxjs": "~7.5.0"

Comment: same here, it's not picking the latest version